# Send TCP data over an "odd" Network Layer instead of IP

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to figure out if there is an easy way to implement this without making my own protocol, so please let me know if there is an "easy" way to do this (preferably in Python).

The crux of my question is this: is there a TCP engine that can handle creating packets if I implement my own "IP" layer?

What I am trying to do is send data communications through a chat room's private message service using base64. So the idea would be:

data -> split into TCP packets -> custom protocol -> chatroom (unreliable) -> read using custom protocol -> reassemble TCP packets -> data

The thing is, I'd rather not implement my own TCP clone if there is some way to use the existing TCP framework and somehow use a callback.

In other words, if I implement my own network layer, can I use that instead of IP?

Comment: Have a look at *dpkt*. It's a Python library which may help. It's poorly documented though.

Comment: What exactly is the "custom protocol"?  Is it already IP, UDP or TCP based?

Comment: As I said in the question, it uses a chat program. I am going to come up with some consistent format for the messages.